# What is the reason behind the very high value of nuclear density?

Tags: nuclear-physics, atomic-physics, atoms, density

I know how to arrive at the formula but I want to know it's such a huge number almost 2 X 10<sup>17</sup> kg m<sup>-3</sup>, which is a huge number, all the more surprising to me is that it's a constant!

Each and every atom in this universe has a nucleus and what happens to spacetime in this situation?

Also since it's a constant, what about the atoms like Hydrogen, one proton and such a high density!

Also what does this tell us about an aton, nature. Basically, what all does this imply?

I hope my understanding of the topic is correct and correct if I'm not.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: (Note - attaching units to numbers is a good thing). I will point out that the strong force is called that because it is holding the nucleus together. It implies nothing in particular about spacetime. I think the question is across the boundary in to metaphysics and philosophy. If you have a more definite physics question in there, please edit accordingly.

Comment: @JonCuster I have added the units, which statement according to you do you think that is question go into metaphysics and philosophy?

Comment: *Also what does this tell us about an atom, nature. Basically, what all does this imply?* That an atom is something like 99.99 % (not a calculated number, for illustrative purposes only) *vacuum*, and by extension so is almost every object we can see. Material objects are mostly empty space and their perceived solidity is an illusion. The QM model of the atom bears this out perfectly, of course.

Comment: The surprising constancy of density is called "The Saturation of Nuclear Matter." This is the most interesting aspect of your question. Perhaps you could edit your question to emphasize this part.

Answer (score 1):

That the nuclear density is very high, but very similar for all sorts of different nuclei does tell us a couple of fundamental things.

First, because it is much higher than the bulk densities of materials (unless we're talking about neutron stars), it tells us that nuclei occupy a *very* small percentage of the space occupied by an atom.

Second, if nuclei consist of differing collections of neutrons and protons, but the nuclear density remains (roughly) constant, it tells us that the nucleons are behaving like solid billiard balls in the way that they pack together. i.e. That they are packed together very tightly, but once they get to a certain separation, there must be a strong repulsive force that stops them getting any closer - a bit like a hard surface. These are indeed the characteristics exhibited by the strong nuclear force - the nucleons are really only affected by their nearest neighbours, because the strong nuclear force is short-range, and nucleons repel each other strongly if they approach much closer than about $10^{-15}$ m.